# EMMA coverage.ec not generated

Tags: java, tomcat, emma

I want to know the code coverage of a website running on tomcat apache.I have tried many times to  get the coverage.ec file.
But it is not coming.

Steps followed:

1. Copied emma.jar into classpath
2. Instrumented the code and got coverage.em
3. Restarted server and checked the tomcat log
4. Log is showing: EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ... during startup
5. I have then launch the site and navigating to many pages
6. Stopped the tomcat.

As checked in another thread, after stopping the server, the last line of log will show coverage.ec path and log.
But it is not there in my case.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to catalina.properties
emma.coverage.out.file=/tmp/coverage.ec